# Why doesn't the prefab change in the app?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Such a problem: from the script, I change the image of the sprite of  SpriteRenderer component (like another skin) in a certain prefab, having a link to SpriteRenderer. And the problem is that when I run the game in unity, everything works, i.e. the skin changes. And when I run it in the app (apk file), the skin doesn't change. Why is that?

```
[SerializeField] SpriteRenderer player; // in the inspector, I drag the player's prefab to this field
[SerializeField] Sprite[] skins; // here I drag the player's images (skins)
int i = Random.Range(0, skins.Length);
player.sprite = skins[i]; // this is how I assign the skin to the player
```

Comment: Are you sure You have saved scene after dragging your players prefab to this field?

Comment: Absolutely. If I didn't do this, it wouldn't work in the editor, and I wouldn't be able to build  the game

Comment: Any errors in logcat?

Comment: Nothing, I checked. I will try to build the app again, maybe there was a problem during the build

Comment: No, there were no problems during the build. This is strange. I think the prefabs field is just not included in the APK file.

Comment: No, because if prefabs field are not included in APK, these fields are null. So C# will generate exception when You'll try to access them. Can You please provide some link on your project or give me project example. Ill try to produce this error myself. You can write me in telegram also: @selezen88

Comment: Look, what I found: https://forum.unity.com/threads/changing-sprite-on-prefab-works-for-multiple-scenes-in-editor-but-not-on-android.233106/. It seems I'm not the only one who has encountered this problem. Actually I bypassed this by loading the skin in the prefab script when it was activated